Imprimir en input un valor devuelto formato JSON
Tengo un problema al tratar de llenar un campo de tipo input con el resultado de un ajax y formateado a tipo JSON
la respuesta del controlador es esta
[{"cedper":"0000000000","nomper":"YAMPIER","apeper":"LOPEZ","telhabper":"","telmovper":"","desuniadm":"COORDINACION DE TELECOMUNICACIONES","codnom":"8003","minorguniadm":"2001","ofiuniadm":"09","uniuniadm":"05","depuniadm":"00","prouniadm":"00","staper":"1","desubifis":"Sin Ubicacion"}]

trato de mostrarlo de la siguiente manera pero me da el mesaje de "undefined"
console.log(persona[0].nomper)

si lo coloco sin el índice 0 igual me da undefined
este es el codigo del ajax
$.ajax({
                url : '/buscar_persona',
                method : 'post',
                datatype : 'JSON',
                data : {
                    "_token" : "{{csrf_token()}}",
                    cedula : cedula
                }, success : function(persona){
                    console.log(persona[0].nomper)

                    //var persona = $.parseJSON(persona)
                    var fullName = persona[0].nomper +' '+persona[0].apeper

                    if(typeof(persona[0] != '')){
                        $("#nombresYapellidos").val(persona.nomper)//.prop('readonly',false)
                        $("#acueducto").val('')//.prop('readonly',false)
                        $("#gerencia").val('')//.prop('readonly',false)
                        $("#telefonoHab").val('')//.prop('readonly',false)
                        $("#tipo_persona")//.attr('disabled',false)
                    }else{
                        $("#nombresYapellidos").val(persona.nombre_apellido).prop('readonly',true)
                        $("#acueducto").val(persona.acueducto).prop('readonly',true)
                        $("#gerencia").val(persona.gerencia).prop('readonly',true)
                        $("#tipo_persona").val('EMPLEADO').prop('readonly',true)
                    }

                    if(persona.voto == 'SI'){
                        Swal.fire({
                          icon: "error",
                          title: "Persona Ya Voto",
                          text: "Verifica el Número de Cédula",
                        });
                    }

                    if(persona.telhabper == ''){
                        $("#telefonoHab").val('No Posee')
                    }else{
                        $("#telefonoHab").val(persona.telefono)
                    }
                }


al darle el tipo de data al ajax proba con el case dataType: "json",  ( camelcase el properti y lowercase el type )

¿Puedes intentar con alguna de las siguientes opciones y ver si funciona?
success : function(persona){

               
                persona=JSON.parse(persona)

                console.log(persona[0].nomper)
                //var persona = $.parseJSON(persona)
                var fullName = persona[0].nomper +' '+persona[0].apeper

                if(typeof(persona[0] != '')){

.....
la segunda opcion es:
 persona = JSON.parse(persona.d)


Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
